# How to fix ProGuard bugs

Tags: java, android, proguard

In my application i want enable proguard and write proguard rules, but after generate apk show me some errors in in **logcat**.

In my application i want enable proguard and write proguard rules, but after generate apk show me some errors in in **logcat**.

**Show me this error :**

```
Error: D:\Projects\myapp\BaseApp\1.0.22\app\proguard-rules.pro, offset: 3207, line: 88, column: 7, Expected [!]interface|@interface|class|enum
```

ProGuard rules:

```
##########################
#        OKHTTP          #
##########################
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-keepnames class okhttp3.internal.publicsuffix.PublicSuffixDatabase
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.*
-dontwarn okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform
##########################
#        OKIO            #
##########################
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.*
##########################
#        RETROFIT        #
##########################
-keepattributes Signature, InnerClasses, EnclosingMethod
-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleAnnotations, RuntimeVisibleParameterAnnotations
-keepclassmembers,allowshrinking,allowobfuscation interface * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn kotlin.Unit
-dontwarn retrofit2.KotlinExtensions
-dontwarn retrofit2.KotlinExtensions$*
-if interface * { @retrofit2.http.* <methods>; }
-keep,allowobfuscation interface <1>
##########################
#        GSON            #
##########################
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-dontwarn sun.misc.**
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { <fields>; }
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapter
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
  @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}
##########################
#        GLIDE           #
##########################
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public class * extends com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.ImageHeaderParser$** {
  **[] $VALUES;
  public *;
}
##########################
#        ROOM            #
##########################
-keep class * extends androidx.room.RoomDatabase
-dontwarn androidx.room.paging.**
##########################
#       EVENTBUS         #
##########################
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe <methods>;
}
-keep enum org.greenrobot.eventbus.ThreadMode { *; }
-keepclassmembers class * extends org.greenrobot.eventbus.util.ThrowableFailureEvent {
    <init>(java.lang.Throwable);
}
##########################
#          YOYO          #
##########################
-keep class com.daimajia.easing.** { *; }
-keep interface com.daimajia.easing.* { *; }
-keep class com.daimajia.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.daimajia.**
-keepnames class com.daimajia.**
##########################
#        PDFVIEW         #
##########################
-keep class com.shockwave.**
##########################
#      DOWNLOADER        #
##########################
-keep class com.downloader.** {*;}
##########################
#       MY_FILES         #
##########################
-dontwarn com.app.app.data.model.**
-keep class com.app.app.data.model.** { *;}
-dontwarn com.app.app.utils.custom_view.**
-keep com.app.app.utils.custom_view.** { *;}
```

Show me error for **line 88** and **line 88** is `-keep com.app.app.utils.custom_view.** { *;}` !

How can i fix it?

Comment: `-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.*` multiple times

Comment: which is line 88??

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya , thanks my friend, but again show me below error : `offset: 3065, line: 84, column: 7, Expected [!]interface|@interface|class|enum`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya, can you help me? please

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya , when remove this lines build whit out any error : `-dontwarn com.app.app.data.model.**
-keep class com.app.app.data.model.** { *;}
-dontwarn com.app.app.utils.custom_view.**
-keep com.app.app.utils.custom_view.** { *;}`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya , but i want don't proguard my specific files and folders! how can i fix it? please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error specifies, you have a syntax error in your ProGuard rules which is after the keyword `keep` you need to specify the type before providing the name.

In this case you are missing the word `class`.

Just change the line

```
-keep com.app.app.utils.custom_view.** { *;}
```

to

```
-keep class com.app.app.utils.custom_view.** { *;}
```

For more information about customizing your rules file, read the [ProGuard Manual](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/usage).